# Why benzene is more easily reduced by Birch reduction than by catalytic hydrogenation?

Tags: organic-chemistry

As far as I know, H2,Pd is a better reducing agent than Na in liquid ammonia.
However, Na in liquid ammonia can reduce benzene at low temperature conditon of about -30°C.
Moreover, it is hard for H2,Pd to reduce benzene and requires very high temperature and pressure.

Comment: The very short version is that these two reactions have substantially different mechanisms with different rate-determining steps and activation energies.

Comment: But how can having an anion radical mechanism reduce the activation energy to such an extent?

Comment: Because the mechanisms are different, the activation energies are not easily comparable. The Birch reduction starts with a single electron transfer to one of the LUMOs of benzene to form a radical anion that is still partially aromatic. Catalytic hydrogenation starts with a concerted syn addition of the $\ce{H2}$ molecule to form a neutral non-aromatic intermediate.